# IF and ELSE Statement based on column value

Tags: sql, if-statement

Based on one column within my query results (Value), I am trying to write an if/else statement based on the value held which will display the result the in an additional row.

For example, if I have a record of 2 within the value field, but I want to check whether it is above < 5. If the value is less than 5 I basically want the additional column to display a hardcoded value of 5, else display actual value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a sidenote : conditional logic inside of SQL statements almost always is a programming mistake - SQL is ugly, slow in terms of actual algorithms and nigh-unmaintainable. Use a proper ORM and write "pretty" code - thats how the professionals do it ... and there are a lot of reasons for it

Comment: @specializt using an ORM for a result that's just a `CASE` expression doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: in fact, its a **very** good idea since his application will almost assuredly use many more statements than just this single one - the world isnt flat just because you cant see its curvature with your own eyes, you know ... just sayian

Comment: Feedback taken onboard - Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `case` statement

```
select a.*, 
       case
           when a.TheField < 5 then 5
           else a.TheField
       end as NewField
from MyTable a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case`

```
select value, case when value < 5 
                   then 5 
                   else value 
              end as calculated_column
from your_table
```